# Is the 960px grid system still a standard for web design?

Tags: html, css

I've been taking a comprehensive Udemy course on web development and the 960px grid system has been mentioned a few times. Since the course seems to be a couple years old, I'd like to ask if this is still a standard in web design.

The main reason why I ask this is that most "recent" sites that I've visited display their content screen-wide and not on a narrow 960px column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask this on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. This is not a problem with some code.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise, therefore I voted to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Use a page/column width that is based on your content, user base, what devices they're using, etc, not just what the cool kids are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No.**

The answer is opinion-based, but today's webdesign with things like responsiveness in mind has gotten far away from using 960 pixels. In fact even pixels have more or less been replaced by percentages and more flexible units.

Anyway: It hasn't been something I would have called 'standard'.